# Issue with programmatically scrolling to top of UITableView or to first TableViewCell with iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uikit

In iOS 10.3, it is possible to programmatically scroll to the top of a UITableView with any one of the following lines of code:

```
// assumes indexPathOfFirstRow defined
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPathOfFirstRow, at: .top, animated: true)

self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0), animated: true)

self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

In iOS 11 and in current iOS 11.2, these lines of code will scroll the table view to near the top but often not to the first cell or to the very top.

scrollToRow seems working but it results in UI glitches.

Does anyone experiencing these kind of issues or using any workaround?

Comment: Does the table view have a non-zero top content inset?

Comment: @the4kman no, all the content insets are zero

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. It's working on my end.

```
var cellrect = self.tableview.rectForSection(1) 


self.tableview.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y: cellrect.origin.y), animated: true)
```

Comment: it is the same behavior, it scrolls near to the top but not to the very top